# How do I obtain the current Windows logon/user id from within Base SAS?

Tags: sas

I am running Windows Xp. Is there a way in Base SAS to obtain the logon id of the current user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%put &SYSUSERID;

Comment: it's an automatic macro variable.